# How to set data from array list to another array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, collections

i'm working in Android Application, i'm looking how to display results from array list after for loop, i want to set every value (heure, minute ...) in another list view after the function of conversion (BCD to Integer)  that i'm worked with. thank you for your help!!

```
Integer[] array = {heure, minute, seconde, jour, mois, year};
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    /*Collections.addAll(list, array);*/
    for (int value : list) {
        temp = value;
        temp >>= 4;
        result = temp * 10;
        temp = value & 0b00001111;
        result += temp;
        this.total= result;
        list.add(this.total);
    }
    tvGetdata.setText(list.toString());
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what your actual question is or where you are stuck?

Comment: i want to display every value converted in another arraylist

Answer (score 1):

You're using a foreach on a empty list.
So your code will just ignore it.
Try do your for using your array.

```
Integer[] array = {heure, minute, seconde, jour, mois, year};
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int value : array) {
    temp = value;
    temp >>= 4;
    result = temp * 10;
    temp = value & 0b00001111;
    result += temp;
    this.total= result;
    list.add(this.total);
}
tvGetdata.setText(list.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You kind of misused the two data structures here.

- an `Array` is a fixed length list of items

  - use it whenever you have a fixed set of values you want to process
- a `List` is a list of items that will (at least in standard implementations) always try to adapt its capacatiy to the number of items

  - use it whenever you need something more dynamic than an `Array`

So, in conclusion you will get a better outcome by switching the usage of these to structures (you'll se why below).

```
// we exactly know our initial input, so we can use an Array here
Integer[] array = {heure, minute, seconde, jour, mois, year};

// we don't know how many items will go in here, so we use a List for now
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

// you can loop over an Array just as over a List
for (int value : array) {
    // TODO do your calculations and save them in this.result

    // the ArrayList provides this neat utility to add an element
    // it will automatically increase its capacity, if required
    list.add(this.result);
}
tvGetdata.setText(list.toString());
```

Of course you can replace the `array` variable with another `List` and set the elements from a `List` to a `List`. The basic construct is just the same.

Comment: thank u but it display empty list, no value was  inserted !

Comment: it display always the last data ( year) and not the 6 together

Comment: No idea what could be wrong, it works for me. Could you please show how you implemented my example, e.g. by editing your question?

Comment: @D.G You are looping over the empty `List`, not over the populated `Array`.

Comment: @Izuro sorry i didn't understand what do you mean :/

Comment: @D.G In the code it's `for (int value : list)` vs `for (int value : array)`.